# how to compare two different files with coordinates and write the common coordinates and new coordinates to a new file?

Tags: r

I'm trying to compare two different files with coordinates and write the common coordinates and new/old coordinates to a new file. I actually believed - operator would work! But then again I'm still new to R and that was a rookie mistake. 
Adder and removed are the files with coordinates. And I'm not sure how to proceed anymore. I had a for loop following the code I've provided here. But I chose to remove it so that I will look less of an idiot than actually I am :) I'm trying to get the common coordinates out of the comparison as 'common' and the other coordinates regardless of the common coordinates from removed.csv to 'new coordinates' and like wise the rest of the coordinates from adder.csv to 'old coordinates'. Please advise ..

```
library(plyr)

adder <- read.csv(file="//eudrrs09/common/99_User/99_schallj/_tmp/adder1.csv",header=TRUE, sep = ";", fill = TRUE)
adder1 <- data.frame("x"=adder$X, "y"=adder$Y)

removed <- read.csv(file="//eudrrs09/common/99_User/99_schallj/_tmp/removed1.csv",header=TRUE, sep = ";", fill = TRUE)
removed1 <- data.frame("x"=removed$X, "y"=removed$Y)

z <- adder1 - removed1
count(z, c("x", "y"))
```

Comment: Could you provide a small sample of your data and what is your desired output?

Comment: for example @nicola, adder is a file that contains coordinates like                    23,883 6,423
23,985 6,421
23,996 6,429
24,003 6,395
 and removed could be,                                                                  23,883 6,423
50,985 66,421
25,996 16,429
24,003 6,395
I'd like to compare these two files, get the common coordinates, get the other coordinates regardless of the common coordinates from removed to 'new coordinates' and rest of the coordinates from adder to 'old coordinates'.

Answer (score 0):

To show an approach, I created a mock set of coordinates (cities in Wyoming, USA) in the adder object.

```
dput(adder)
structure(list(V1 = c(42.06, 44.63, 44.08, 41.41, 42.66, 44.53, 
41.94, 41.18, 39.02), V2 = c(-104.18, -104.18, -104.13, -104.1, 
-104.09, -104.08, -104.07, -104.06, -84.56), interact = c("42.06-104.18", 
"44.63-104.18", "44.08-104.13", "41.41-104.1", "42.66-104.09", 
"44.53-104.08", "41.94-104.07", "41.18-104.06", "39.02-84.56"
)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "interact"), row.names = c(NA, -9L
), class = "data.frame")

Then I used the same coordinates of adder plus a handful of new ones, in removed.

dput(removed)
structure(list(V1 = c(41.91, 41.53, 41.79, 43.84, 42.06, 44.63, 
44.08, 41.41, 42.66, 44.53, 41.94, 41.18, 39.02), V2 = c(-104.29, 
-104.27, -104.27, -104.21, -104.18, -104.18, -104.13, -104.1, 
-104.09, -104.08, -104.07, -104.06, -84.56), interact = c("41.91-104.29", 
"41.53-104.27", "41.79-104.27", "43.84-104.21", "42.06-104.18", 
"44.63-104.18", "44.08-104.13", "41.41-104.1", "42.66-104.09", 
"44.53-104.08", "41.94-104.07", "41.18-104.06", "39.02-84.56"
)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "interact"), row.names = c(NA, -13L
), class = "data.frame")
```

The next step was simple: paste the coordinates together into a new variable.

```
adder$interact <- paste(adder$V1, adder$V2, sep = "")
removed$interact <- paste(removed$V1, removed$V2, sep = "")

adder
         V1      V2     interact
    1 42.06 -104.18 42.06-104.18
    2 44.63 -104.18 44.63-104.18
    3 44.08 -104.13 44.08-104.13
    4 41.41 -104.10  41.41-104.1
    5 42.66 -104.09 42.66-104.09
    6 44.53 -104.08 44.53-104.08
    7 41.94 -104.07 41.94-104.07
    8 41.18 -104.06 41.18-104.06
    9 39.02  -84.56  39.02-84.56
```

Finally, use `setdiff` to spot the non-matched coordinates.  You can later split them apart if you need to.

```
new.coordinates <- setdiff(removed$interact, adder$interact)
new.coordinates
[1] "41.91-104.29" "41.53-104.27" "41.79-104.27" "43.84-104.21"
```